How to Manage Automated WhatsApp Bots for Multiple Tenants with Unique Phone Numbers in a Multi-Tenant Application?
I have a multi-tenant application where each tenant (client) can manage their products and interact with their customers through WhatsApp. Here’s my setup and the problem I’m facing:

I have 70 tenants in my application, and each tenant needs their own WhatsApp bot to communicate with customers.
Each bot requires a unique phone number to function.
I am using the WhatsApp Business Cloud API and have an account named XYZ.
I was able to add two phone numbers to the XYZ account, but I encountered a limitation when trying to add more numbers.
Each bot needs to send and receive messages independently, and I also need to process webhook events for each bot separately to handle tenant-specific logic.

Questions:

How can I support 70 tenants, each with a unique phone number and WhatsApp bot, using the WhatsApp Business Cloud API?
Is there a way to overcome the limitation of adding multiple phone numbers to a single WhatsApp Business Account?
How can I set up and handle webhook events efficiently for each tenant in a multi-tenant architecture?

What I’ve Tried:

Adding multiple phone numbers to the XYZ account but encountered a limit after two numbers.
Researching WhatsApp’s documentation and community forums but couldn’t find a clear solution for this type of multi-tenant setup.

What I Need:
I’m looking for a scalable solution that:

Allows each tenant to have their own bot and unique phone number.
Ensures webhook events are processed correctly for each tenant, considering their specific logic.


Your question has two distinct parts, and the second one is more tricky/complex as it depends on the architecture you want to implement. Please provide more design info, so we can assist you better.

Is there a way to overcome the limitation of adding multiple phone numbers to a single WhatsApp Business Account?

Yes, you need to Verify Your Business. Once verified, you can add more business numbers. Follow Meta's instructions here:
Meta Business Verification

How can I support 70 tenants, each with a unique phone number and WhatsApp bot, using the WhatsApp Business Cloud API?

This depends on the architecture and programming language you’re using. Here’s a scalable approach to handle this scenario in a multi-tenant setup:

Pub/Sub Architecture: Use a central queue to route messages, needed because whatsapp only accepts ONE WEBHOOK URL. and workers consume messages when they have available capacity.
Redis Queues with python workers: Each tenant gets a queue and process these messages independently.

Message Gateway:
import redis

redis_client = redis.StrictRedis()

def enqueue_message(message):
    tenant_id = message["metadata"]["phone_number_id"]  # Unique for each WhatsApp number
    queue_name = f"queue:{tenant_id}"
    redis_client.rpush(queue_name, message)

Worker:
import time

def processor_1(tenant_id, message):
    print(f"First Processor {tenant_id}: {message}")

def processor_2(tenant_id, message):
    print(f"Second Processor {tenant_id}: {message}")

def worker(tenant_id):
    queue_name = f"queue:{tenant_id}"
    while True:
        message = redis_client.lpop(queue_name)
        if message:
            if tenant_id == "foo": 
                processor_1(tenant_id, message)
            else:
                processor_2(tenant_id, message)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)  # No messages, wait and retry

This is a simplified example. For a more comprehensive implementation (and I run in production), you can refer to this example:
Whatsapp Message Gateway + Multiple workers Example
